# Неактивна кнопка New Trigger.. в SQL Server Management Studio 2014

Tags: sql-server, триггер

Неактивна кнопка "New Trigger.". в SQL Server Management Studio 2014
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я думаю дело в известном баге 2014 SSMS.
["New trigger" is disabled.](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/873249/ssms-2014-new-trigger-is-disabled-for-older-2012-2008r2-versions-of-sql-server)
Вы можете создать триггер таким способом:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerName
    ON [dbo].[TableName]
    FOR DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE
    AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    END
```